# How do I factor out my use of `try {...} catch (Error e) {log_error(e);}`

Tags: error-handling, closures, vala

I need errors to be logged in the same way across a large number of function calls. Here I want errors from `foo.create(...)` and `File.new_tmp(...)` to be logged by `handle_error(...)`.

```cs
// compile with `valac --pkg gio-2.0 main.vala` 

void log_error(Error e) {
    // error logging here
}

void main() {
    var foo = File.new_for_path("foo");
    try {
        foo.create(FileCreateFlags.NONE);
    } catch (Error e) {
        log_error(e);
    }

    FileIOStream tmp_stream;
    try {
        File.new_tmp(null, out tmp_stream);
    } catch (Error e) {
        log_error(e);
    }
}
```

*(Yes, `main` should continue with the `FileIOStream` stuff if `foo.create` fails, which is why they're in separate `try/catch` blocks.)*

I want to factor out the use of `try {...} catch (Error e) {log_error(e);}` into a function like so:

```cs
delegate void Action();

void log_error(global::Action action) {
    try {
        action();
    } catch (Error e) {
        // error logging here
    }
}

void main() {
    var foo = File.new_for_path("foo");
    log_error(() => foo.create(FileCreateFlags.NONE));

    FileIOStream tmp_stream;
    log_error(() => File.new_tmp(null, out tmp_stream));
}
```

But valac gives the warning `unhandled error 'GLib.IOError'` because you can't seem to catch errors thrown within a closure, nor can I just rewrite `log_error(...)` as a `#define` macro as vala doesn't support them. So what can I do?

Comment: @Crowder `new_for_path` can't throw an error according to [valadoc](http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.File.new_for_path), but this is just some slightly convoluted example code anyway.

Comment: @Crowder In my real application, my error handling code just tells the user something screwed up, I just didn't want people to have to read through lots of unrelated code.

Comment: Oooooh I know what you mean! I'm really sorry, I though you were bugging me about irrelevant stuff lol. The answer is no, `main` doesn't need to return when those functions error. I've edited the question to be less dumb.

Comment: I know *nothing* about vala, but FWIW, seems like a bug -- if your `log_error` accepts a delegate that catches errors, it seems like your thing above should work. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch exceptions thrown in closures, you just need to have the delegate throw the exception.  What you want is probably something like this:

```cs
public delegate T? Action<T> () throws GLib.Error;

T? log_error<T> (global::Action<T> func) {
  try {
    return func ();
  } catch (GLib.Error e) {
    // error logging here
    return null;
  }
}

void main () {
  var foo = File.new_for_path("foo");
  log_error<GLib.FileOutputStream> (() => foo.create (FileCreateFlags.NONE));

  FileIOStream? tmp_stream = null;
  GLib.File? f = log_error<GLib.File> (() => File.new_tmp (null, out tmp_stream));
}
```

Note that I've made it a generic so you can actually use a return value.  If you want it should be trivial to remove the generic type argument and just return void, though you'll lose some flexivility.

Comment: `log_error<GLib.File>` returns a nullable `GLib.File`. In that case it should be `GLib.File? f = log_error<GLib.File> (...);`, right?